# Sending PHP Variable to more pages

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a problem. I am sending variable **c_prot** to page **parsing.php**.
It works, but I need to send **c_prot** at the same time also to page **chart.php** but it doesnt work. If you solve similar problem or you know how to do it I will be very thankuful if you help me.

Thanks a lot!:)

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#generuj').submit(function()
{
    $.post('parsing.php',
    {
        c_prot : $('select#protokoly option:selected').val()
    },
    function(data)
    {
        if(data == 'no')
        {
            $('#refresh').html('Chyba')
        }
        else
        {
            $('#refresh').html(data);  //  START
            $('chart_plot').click(function() 
                      {
                        document.location.reload();
                      });

                   //END
        }
    });

    $.post('chart.php',
    {
    c_prot : $('select#protokoly option:selected').val() 
    });
    return false;   
});
});
```

Comment: is there some problem with using two post functions?

Comment: I tried that, but it doesnt work, this script is connected with Submit button

Comment: Or do you have an idea how to add another post function to my code?:)

Comment: can you submit a sample of what you tried? In the case of two post functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use a location refresh, your page is probably throwing away anything it gets back from chart.php.  Try this:

```
$.post('parsing.php',
{
    c_prot : $('select#protokoly option:selected').val()
},
function(data)
{
    $.post('chart.php',
    {
        c_prot : $('select#protokoly option:selected').val()
    }).done(function(){
       if(data == 'no')
       {
           $('#refresh').html('Chyba')
       }
       else
       {
           $('#refresh').html(data);  //  START
           $('chart_plot').click(function() 
                     {
                       document.location.reload();
                     });

                  //END
       }
    });
});
```

This way, you are calling your second post when you hear back from the first one, but before you refresh the page.

Comment: sorry man, i am not good at it i am still learning. I edited and paste here again above but still doesnt work. Is there any mistake please?